# cURL cookie negative cookie expire

Tags: php, curl

I have problems with cookies with cURL.

After problems I turned on verbose function and figured out cURL sets them negative expire date even if server sends positive date.

Example:

```
* Added cookie _c_sess=""test"" for domain test.com, path /, expire -1630024962
< Set-Cookie: _c_sess="test"; Domain=test.com; HttpOnly; expires=Mon, 26-Mar-2012 14:52:47 GMT; Max-Age=1332773567; Path=/
```

As you can see both expires and max-age are positive, but cURL sets expire to negative value.

Somebody has idea?

EDIT:

Here is php code I use.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://site.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiepath);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiepath);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR  ,$f);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Data from cookie jar:

```
#HttpOnly_.test.com TRUE    /   FALSE   -1630016318 _test_sess  "test"
```

Comment: Show the code that does this, especially the code that generates that negative timestamp.

Comment: Please add the code you use to add that cookie.

Comment: okay i added data from cookie jar

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. Your example site, *http://www.site.com/* does not even attempt to set any cookies. When I ran it against sites that set cookies (i.e. FaceBook), I got positive expiration times.

The error is probably an issue on the server that is trying to set cookies that is setting an incorrect value.

> Any negative number will expire the cookie immediately ([cite](http://webpy.org/cookbook/cookies)).

My best guess, the site is trying to expire your cookie.

Comment: No way because site passes valid expire date, I guess it is the bug in curl because header also contains max-age parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the same issue as [Curl doesn't recognize expires value in cookie correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091423/curl-doesnt-recognize-expires-value-in-cookie-correctly) - "You are experiencing an issue on your computer because of the limits of 32 bit signed integer values."