# Curl doesn't recognize expires value in cookie correctly

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'm trying to perfom a log-in on pinterest.com with curl.  I got the following request-response-flow:

1. GET-Request the login form and scrape hidden fields (csrftoken)
2. POST-Request login credentials (mail and pw) and scraped csrftoken
3. Receive Session Cookie for login

Using Curl, I can see the following Headers being sent and received:

```
 GET /login/?next=%2F HTTP/1.1
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2
 Host: pinterest.com
 Referer:
 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,*/*
 Accept-Language: de-de,en-us
 Connection: keep-alive

 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
 Date: Tue, 10 Apr 2012 15:03:24 GMT
 ETag: "45d6a85f0ede46f13f4fc751842ce5b7"
 Server: nginx/0.8.54
 Set-Cookie: csrftoken=dec6cb66064f318790c6d51e3f3a9612; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
 Set-Cookie: _pinterest_sess="eJyryMwNcTXOdtI3zXcKNq0qznIxyXVxK/KqSsy3tY8vycxNtfUN8a3yc3E09nXxLPdztLVVK04tLs5MsfXNAopVpVf6VnlW+Qba2gIAuqgZIg=="; Domain=pinterest.com; HttpOnly; expires=Tue, 17-Apr-2012 15:03:24 GMT; Max-Age=1334675004; Path=/
 Vary: Cookie, Accept-Encoding
 Content-Length: 4496
 Connection: keep-alive
```

So after step 1, the two cookies csrftoken and _pinterest_sess are set. But a look in the cookiejar file (I use CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR to let curl handle the cookie processing) shows the following:

```
   # Netscape HTTP Cookie File
   # http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
   # This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

   pinterest.com        FALSE        /        FALSE        1365519805        csrftoken        dec6cb66064f318790c6d51e3f3a9612
   #HttpOnly_.pinterest.com        TRUE        /        FALSE        -1626222087        _pinterest_sess        "eJyryMwNcTXOdtI3zXcKNq0qznIxyXVxK/KqSsy3tY8vycxNtfUN8a3yc3E09nXxLPdztLVVK04tLs5MsfXNAopVpVf6VnlW+Qba2gIAuqgZIg=="
```

First thing to note is the #HttpOnly_ in preceding the _pinterest_sess cookie line. I just assume that curl handles that just fine. But looking further, one can see that a negative value is set as expiration date: -1626222087

I don't know where that's coming from, because the cookie is set with "expires=Tue, 17-Apr-2012 15:03:24 GMT" (which is about 7 days in the future, counting from today).

On the next request, the _pinterest_sess cookie won't be set by curl:

```
 POST /login/?next=%2F HTTP/1.1
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2
 Host: pinterest.com
 Referer: https://pinterest.com/login/?next=%2F
 Cookie: csrftoken=dec6cb66064f318790c6d51e3f3a9612
 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,*/*
 Accept-Language: de-de,en-us
 Connection: keep-alive
 Content-Length: 123
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
 Date: Tue, 10 Apr 2012 15:05:26 GMT
 ETag: "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
 Location: http://pinterest.com/
 Server: nginx/0.8.54
 Set-Cookie: _pinterest_sess="eJzLcssPCy4NTclIjvAOrjQzyywoCChISgvLDi+2tY9PrSjILEottvUN8a3yc4k09gtxrfRLt7VVK04tLs5MAYonV/qGeFb4ZkWW+4LES4tTi+KBEv4u6UZ+WYEmvlm+QOxZ6R/iWOEbEmgLAKNfJps="; Domain=pinterest.com; HttpOnly; expires=Tue, 17-Apr-2012 15:05:26 GMT; Max-Age=1334675126; Path=/
 Vary: Cookie
 Content-Length: 0
 Connection: keep-alive
```

In the response, another _pinterest_sess cookie is set since curl didn't send the last one.

Currently, I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if curl just isn't able to parse the expires value in the cookie correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

// edit
One more thing: 
According to http://opensource.apple.com/source/curl/curl-57/curl/lib/cookie.c the function curl_getdate() is used to extract the date. The documentation on that function lists some examples (http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_getdate.html):

- Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT
- Sunday, 06-Nov-94 08:49:37 GMT
- Sun Nov 6 08:49:37 1994
- 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT
- 06-Nov-94 08:49:37 GMT
- Nov 6 08:49:37 1994
- 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37
- 06-Nov-94 08:49:37
- 1994 Nov 6 08:49:37 GMT
- 08:49:37 06-Nov-94
- Sunday 94 6 Nov 08:49:37
- 1994 Nov 6
- 06-Nov-94
- Sun Nov 6 94
- 1994.Nov.6
- Sun/Nov/6/94/GMT
- Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 CET
- 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 EST
- Sun, 12 Sep 2004 15:05:58 -0700
- Sat, 11 Sep 2004 21:32:11 +0200
- 20040912 15:05:58 -0700
- 20040911 +0200

None of them matches the above mentioned expires date "Tue, 17-Apr-2012 15:03:24 GMT" because all examples with hyphens only use 2-digit-years..

Comment: "Tue, 17-Apr-2012 15:03:24 GMT" looks like a JavaScript `Date.toGMTString()` kind of output. I've had issues juggling between that and PHP before since it's not a format that seems to be recognised by PHP's date and time formatting (as used by `strtotime()` for instance)... might be worth trying generate `(int)` based timestamps instead.

Comment: Did you find any solution to the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You are experiencing an issue on your computer because of the limits of 32 bit signed integer values.

The server sets a cookie with the *Max-Age* of 1334675004 seconds in the future.

```
Max-Age=1334675004
```

You posted your question here @ 2012-04-10 15:13:24Z. That is a UNIX timestamp of 1334070804. If you add 1334675004 to it and you take a 32 bit integer limit of 2147483647 into account while having an integer roundtrip, you'll get: -1626221485:

```
  1334070804
+ 1334675004
------------
 -1626221485
```

As the numbers show, it looks like that the server did misunderstood the Max-Age attribute, if you substract each values from each other there is a circa delta of 7 days in seconds (604200 = ~6.99 days, the difference is because the cookie was set earlier than you posted your question here). However Max-Age is the delta of seconds, not the absolut UNIX timestamp.

Try to raise `PHP_INT_MAX` with your PHP version, or compile against 64 bit, this should prevent negative numbers. However, the max-age calculation is still broken with the server. You might want to contact pinterest.com and report the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `pinterest.com` is using `Max-age` incorrectly, and that's why curl is deleting this cookie.

From your example, `Max-age` contains timestamp for `Tue, 17-Apr-2012 15:03:24 GMT`, while it should contain number of seconds from request time to this date - `604800` (judging from request time - `Date` header)

What curl is doing is adding `Max-age` value to current timestamp and saving it as signed 32bit integer, hence `-1626222087`.

As for solution - you can try contacting pinterest and report a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not need to contact pinterest site since it is not required to send back to server cookie max age(if you will use cookie for a short period of time or you may calculate yourself correct max age). Just flip the minus sign and it will work meaning it will be send back to server. And it was not all what you have to do. Sometimes depending on login page presented you have to parce hidden fields also(where CSRF tokens resided and that have to match with the same token value in cookie). Moreover, it will sometimes require to change cookies(reset cookie values). So pinterest web site is making harder and harder to login using automated login tools and doing screen scraping. And recently they have changed how their site functions. So all the above mentioned points does not work now. Actually you do not really know when they will change how login works. You have to try and "guess" when change happens. Actually that attitude should be towards not developers but the ones who are threats to security of the system(intruders). You have to think about legality issue of above mentioned points too.   Pinterest has API(although it is down right now) so it is the best and most correct way to use that API (pls see https://github.com/kellan/pinterest.api.php). There you are exchanging messages in a json format. Last option to use m.pinterest.com which is for mobile devices and it is strightforward to use like parce one login html for hidden input fields and resubmit form with correct values (to use it you are again faced with legality issues too). Please consult with pinterest site before using curl like tools or wait until pinterest api is up. Yes, there some improvements in the system like getting json responses which puts the end to screen scraping but that does not mean completely new api. Also right now they(seemingly) implemented web services, restful, api and taking ajax requests which are again  steps towards to positive improvement. There are many discussions are going on the net on this matter so please refer to them for detailed  info.